# increase browser display time

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I am trying to fetch data like Amazon or other sites. The process take time (about one or more hours) to fetch data. But in between the browser get off saying 'Page can not be displayed' in IE and other error in FF and all UI got lost. How to increase browser time to complete the task successfully.

Comment: So, you want to increase the page load timeout, expecting people to wait _more than an hour_ for a page to load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things you could do:

1. Have this happen in an AJAX framework - this ensures UI will continue and you can display a progress indicator
2. Break down into smaller steps, so you can give the user feedback at it goes along
3. Improve the way it works so people don't have to wait that long.